# Question about Python scope (& enumerate function)

Tags: python, loops, indexing, scope, immutability

2 part question.  Given the following code, my understanding is that `i` is a variable created within the loop function. As such, the changes have local scope and should not carry over ‘outside’ the function.

```
list = [3,4,5,6,7]
for element in list:
    i = element * 100
    print(i)
print(i)
```

printing `i` within the loop will produce the correct mathematical change.  However, the second `print(i)` outside the loop returns `700`.  This technically refers to the correct reassignment of element `7` from the original list.  So if changes in the loop only exist within the loop, why is it that this last one carried over ‘outside the loop’?

Furthermore, why is it that `print(i)` outside the loop returns the change to the last element? Why not the first element? Why not all of them? Is there some function I can call outside the loop to see the changes applied to elements 3,4,5,6?

Part 2 of my question - I know for a change to apply outside a loop, you should target the element via its index itself.  Eg use for ‘element’ in `range(len(list))`.  But can one also do this with enumerate?  If so, how?

It seems that enumerate returns an object in the form of a tuple (it adds an ‘index counter’ as the first element, and keeps list as the 2nd element).  And since tuples are immutable it would seem there is no way to effect a change on a global scope, is that correct?

For example, when I run the following code:

```
my_list = [1,2,100]
for xyz in enumerate(my_list):
    xyz = 2 * xyz    
print(xyz)
```

All it does it return to me the final element in my_list, with its index counter, concatenated to itself (‘doubled’). Eg `(2,100)` has become `(2,100, 2,100)`.  So is there no way to use enumerate to change elements within the original list?

Comment: Loops are *not* functions.  Functions create a new local scope, but loops do not.  That's why `i` is able to "leak" outside of the loop.  The reason it maintains the last value from the loop is because, well, it's just a variable.  A variable holds the last value that was assigned to it.

Comment: `enumerate` returns a tuple of `idx, item`.  So to make a change to the original list, one would use e.g. `my_list[idx] = 2 * item`.

Comment: What happens if your list is empty?

Comment: "one would use e.g. my_list[idx] = 2 * item" - you mean discard the for loop and just execute it as one line of code, correct? (as when I try it within the loop, it doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

To your **first question**, let's go through your misunderstandings one by one:

> `i` is a variable created within the loop function

No. There is no "loop function" here. (User @0x5453 already mentioned this briefly in a comment.) The `for`-loop is just a language construct to facilitate iteration. Thus, `i` is just a variable that happens to be created, assigned, and re-assigned multiple times throughout the iteration of the `for`-loop.

> the changes have local scope and should not carry over ‘outside’

See above. There is no other scope here. All those lines of code, starting with the `list` assignment and ending with that `print(i)` after the loop are all in the same scope. This should answer the following of your questions:

> why is it that this last [change] carried over ‘outside the loop’?

> why is it that `print(i)` outside the loop returns the change to the last element?

The variable `i` was re-assigned multiple times. In the last iteration of the `for`-loop, the value assigned to `i` was `7 * 100`, i.e. `700`. Then the loop ends, and nothing else happens to `i`, so it still holds the value `700`.

---

To the **second question**:

> for a change to apply outside a loop, you should target the element via its index itself

If you refer to the your `list`, then the loop has nothing to do with that at all. If you want to change an element of the list, yes, re-assignment only works by targeting the index of that element in the list:

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 100]
my_list[2] = 420
print(my_list)  # output: [1, 2, 420]
```

> can one also do this with enumerate?

No, [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is something else entirely. Calling enumerate on `my_list` returns an iterator, which can then be used in a `for`-loop just like the original list can, but each element that iterator produces is (in its simplest form) a 2-tuple, where the second element is an element from `my_list` and the first element is the index of that element.

Try this:

```py
for tup in enumerate(my_list):
    print(tup[0], tup[1])
```

This will give you:

```
0 1
1 2
2 420
```

Since tuples are iterables, they support [unpacking](https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/), which is why it is common to go for more readability and instead do this:

```py
for idx, element in enumerate(my_list):
    print(idx, element)
```

The output is the same.

Nothing about this changes `my_list`. All these operations do, is iterate over it in some way, which just produces elements from it one by one.

Now, you do this:

```py
for xyz in enumerate(my_list):
    xyz = 2 * xyz
```

Since `xyz` is just that index-element-tuple produced by `enumerate`, multiplying it by `2` just concatenates it with itself, as you correctly noted, creating a new tuple and re-assigning it to `xyz`. In the next iteration it gets overwritten again by what enumerate produces, then re-assigned again by you and so on. Again, none of that changes `my_list`, it just changes that `xyz` variable.

If I understood you correctly, you want to be able to mutate your list within a loop over its elements. While this can quickly lead to dangerous territory, a simple working example would be this:

```py
for idx, element in enumerate(my_list):
    my_list[idx] = 2 * element
print(my_list)
```

The output:

```
[2, 4, 840]
```

**Now** we actually change/re-assign specific elements in that list. As before, assignment only works with an index. But the index is what we get as the first element of the 2-tuple provided by `enumerate` in this case.

However, there are sometimes (arguably) more elegant ways to accomplish the same thing. For instance, we could use list comprehension to achieve the same result:

```py
my_list = [element * 2 for element in my_list]
```

Here we overwrite `my_list` with a new one that we created through list comprehension iterating over the original list.

Hope this helps clear up some misconceptions.

Comment: I see.  So since enumerating my_list outputs a tuple of (x,y), I can simply pass x,y in the for loop.. that is very intuitive!  I understand all the rest.  Thank you very much for your answer, it clarifies everything I misunderstood.